# Javascript recursive function returning undefined instead of expected result

Tags: javascript, recursion, return

I have following function on JSFiddle:

```
function getRandomPointsInRange(range){

        var x1 = rand(1, 40),
            y1 = rand(1, 40),
            x2 = rand(1, 40),
            y2 = rand(1, 40),
            result;

        if(getDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2) < range){
            console.log('test');
            getRandomPointsInRange(range);
        }else{

            result = {x1: x1, y1: y1, x2: x2, y2: y2};
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

It generates two points with distance equal or greater to certain distance (20 in this case). Problem is that sometimes function returns `undefined`, instead of expected result. You can't see that on JS Fiddle, but console log shows that function returns `undefined` only when function calls itself at least once (when `console.log('test')` is triggered. Even when function returns `undefined`, result itself is actually defined as an object(second console.log shows proper object with points coordinates). Why is that happening and how this can be fixed, so proper object would be always returned?

JS Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/3naLztoa/2/

Comment: Finding answers was as simple as Googling words from your title: [site:stackoverflow.com javascript recursive function returns undefined](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+recursive+function+returns+undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prima vista, you need another `return`.

Basically recursive functions need at any exit a value if the function should return a value. If you do not specify one, you get by design, `undefined`.

To prevent this, you have to return the value of another call of a recursive function.

```
function getRandomPointsInRange(range) {
    var x1 = rand(1, 40),
        y1 = rand(1, 40),
        x2 = rand(1, 40),
        y2 = rand(1, 40),
        result;

    if (getDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2) < range) {
        console.log('test');
        return getRandomPointsInRange(range);
       // ^^^^
    } else {
        result = {x1: x1, y1: y1, x2: x2, y2: y2};
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nina says, you need another `return`, and to print json `JSON.stringify` to show the result:

```js
function getDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {

  var result = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
  return result;
};

function rand(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};

function getRandomPointsInRange(range){
  
  var x1 = rand(1, 40),
   y1 = rand(1, 40),
   x2 = rand(1, 40),
   y2 = rand(1, 40),
   result;
   
  if(getDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2) < range){
   return getRandomPointsInRange(range);
  }else{   
   result = {x1: x1, y1: y1, x2: x2, y2: y2};
   return result;
  }
 }
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(getRandomPointsInRange(20));
```

```html
<body>
  <p id="result">

  </p>
</body>
```